# V_SUB_F64 in AMD's GCN and VEGA instruction set

Tags: gpu, opencl, amd-gpu, amd-gcn

Why there is no `V_SUB_F64` instruction in AMD's GCN and VEGA instruction set? How do they realize the double precision subtraction?

[image: As the picture shows]

Answer (score 1):

In section 6.2.1, "Instruction Inputs" of the Instruction Set Architecture document it says:

> Instructions using the VOP3 form and also using floating-point inputs have the option of applying absolute value (ABS field) or negate (NEG field) to any of the input operands.

`V_ADD_F64` is listed as a VOP3-encoded instruction, so you can negate either or both of the operands to produce `(a + b)`, `(a - b)`, `(-a + b)`, or `(-a - b)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. You have solved a big confusion for me.